# Extjs-Window collpased:true not working

Tags: extjs

I have a window with a grid in it, i want to open the window collapsed. but even if i give collapsed:true it dont seem to work...here is my code

```
var gridWindow = new Ext.Window({
    title : title,
    iconCls:'diagramIcon',
    id :id ,
    layout:'fit',
    itemId:nodeId,
    plain:true,
    collapsible:true,
    collapsed:true,
    shadow:false,
    constrain:true,
    animCollapse:true,
    closeAction:'close',
    expandable:true,
    items:[schemaGrid(nodeId,id)],
    height: height, 
    width: width
})
```

can some one help.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `expandOnShow` property as well. Add

```
expandOnShow: false,
```

to your window configurations. Alternatively you can also use the APIs. Display the grid window by:

```
gridWindow.show().collapse(false);
```

This will ensure that the window is collapsed when it is displayed.